# Validate currency in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have an input field and I want to validate it to be a currency. I want it to be in `0.00` format when entering. My check is like below, it does not show the error message when I enter `500.` in the text field. Is something missing below?

```
<cffunction name="checkifDollar" returnType="numeric" access="public">
    <cfargument name="money_val" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfset var_locale = SetLocale("English (US)")>
    <cfset isdollar = 0/>
    <cfif LSIsCurrency(arguments.money_val)>
        <cfset isdollar = 1/>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn isdollar/>
</cffunction>

<cfif !dollarobj.checkifDollar(form.money)>
        <cfset alert_message= "Please enter valid amount in 0.00 format"/>
</cfif>
```

Comment: This code only will run after the form is submitted. You'll need to use JavaScript or the likes to validate the form before submitting, then you can use CF on the back side to make sure what the form sent is actually decimal formatted.

Comment: Or use HTML5 behavior if you aren't concerned with non-modern browsers. <input type='text' pattern='^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$'/>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: `500.` is valid currency. The `00` is assumed. If you want to validate something after the decimal you will need to roll your own.